# uploading with pre signed URL works in postman but failed with 403 on fetch

Tags: javascript, react-native, blob, fetch-api

In React Native 0.70 app, fetch is used to upload a jpg image to OSS. Here is the code:

```js
import ReactNativeBlobUtil from "react-native-blob-util"; //v0.19
fileData = await ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.readFile(filePath);
// fileData is in binary format. the filePath is something similar to after image picker:
// file:///data/user/0/com.xyz_app6/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_97c732b7-48a1-469b-8df1-d42054e5e070.jpg
response = await fetch(preSignedUrl, {
  method: "PUT",
  body: fileData,
});
```

Uploaded failed with 403:

respnose in uploadtooss :

```js
{
  _bodyBlob: {
    _data: {
      __collector: [Object],
      blobId: "56f0bef0-11bb-4b5b-a072-dc70849f0fb6",
      offset: 0,
      size: 959,
    },
  },
  _bodyInit: {
    _data: {
      __collector: [Object],
      blobId: "56f0bef0-11bb-4b5b-a072-dc70849f0fb6",
      offset: 0,
      size: 959,
    },
  },
  bodyUsed: false,
  headers: {
    map: {
      connection: "keep-alive",
      "content-length": "959",
      "content-type": "application/xml",
      date: "Fri, 16 Feb 2024 00:36:02 GMT",
      server: "AliyunOSS",
      "x-oss-ec": "0002-00000040",
      "x-oss-request-id": "65CEADF19BB920313243F0CF",
      "x-oss-server-time": "77",
    },
  },
  ok: false,
  status: 403,
  statusText: "",
  type: "default",
  url: "https://xxxx.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/22790/fWstDM-1000000022.jpg?OSSAccessKeyId=LTAI5t5axvqwo2qGxxxxxxxx&Expires=1708047351&Signature=haslIgyue9yAG71NG9gkomHqxxxxxxxxxx",
};
```

Also tried `base64` format. The uploading was successful but the jpg image uploaded was corrupt (can't open):

```
fileData = await ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.readFile(filePath, 'base64');
```

However when the same pre signed URL is pasted into postman, un-check Content-Type in headers, and choose binary for body and select the jpg file, send is successful. What is missing with the fetch?

Comment: Where does `preSignedUrl` come from in your code? The 403 response suggests the problem is either there or in missing headers

Comment: THe `preSignedUrl` is acquired from the backend nodejs server before uploading. The  `preSignedUrl` is successful in postman to upload a jpg file. However the same `preSignedUrl` is not working when fetch PUT in react native app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to security, Postman usually uses self-signed certs etc to "cheat" a bit, making postman easier to use when you're getting a project up off the ground.  But it's not a good use case to actually test security related functionality such as self-signed urls.

I'd really take a look at the app code for potential problems, CORS issues, etc., and not trust Postman that things are almost working.

Sorry I can't give more detail...  :(   Maybe check the headers your app is/isn't sending...

Comment: `Ron Newcomb`, thank you for the comments. When using ReactNativeBlobUtil.fetch(), there is a success. But the uploaded jpg file (in base64 format) was corrupted. At least it show the pre signed URL did work. But not sure why the uploaded was corrupted.